# How to change Subject property of Certificate Signing Request programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8, cryptography, bouncycastle, csr, pkcs#11

I am implementing Windows MDM. In this, Device sends CSR which is PKCS#10 Certificate request.

When I go to http://certlogik.com/decoder, and decode this CSR,I get Subject as
"CN=B1C43CD0-1624-5FBB-8E54-34CF17DFD3A1\00"

This "\00", we want to remove from subject property.Because of this we are not able to install company hub app during enrolment.

I want to change this subject to any value such as "CN=myMDM".How can I change Subject property of CSR?

Answer (score 3):

It is permissible to have a certificate subject differ from the subject of the PKCS#10 (i.e. CSR). See the -subj option to OpenSSL's 'req' command.

For reasons behind this ability, consider this; Your CSR is signed by your private key. The signature is used to verify that the contents of the CSR have not been modified (this includes the subject). Your public key is included in the CSR. A CA creates your cert and uses whatever parts of the CSR subject it sees fit. The cert, along with the CA-specified subject and the public key from your CSR is signed by the private key of the CA. This signature is used to verify that the contents of your cert have not been modified (this includes the CA-specified subject).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it once you have the certificate request, as CSR's should be signed with your private key, and the signing is definitely including the subject line.

So if you change anything you need to resign, which requires you to parse the CSR. So basically you should rebuild your CSR and simply strip off the character with value `00` (null terminator character) when you supply your common name (CN).

You are left with the following options:

- correctly generate the CSR, as explained above,
- change the CSR, removing the zero valued byte and recalculating all the lengths, and skip verification,
- create a special certificate creator that puts the correct subject like out of the CSR after verifying or skipping the signature verification of the CSR;

Comment: We are generating certificate(to be returned to the device) using this CSR. As Subject of CSR contains null character,so certificate made using CSR also contains null character in its subject property.Due to this null character, hub app does not get installed during enrolment.That's why I need to change subject of certificate.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you *want*, but you cannot do this with any standard certificate creation libraries. Made your options even more clear in the answer.